# CHMOD 400 not working trying to ssh to amazon instance

Tags: command-line

I am trying to ssh to amazon instance with my `.pem` file however `CHMOD 400` is not working as it says “this command is not available”.  It works on my mac terminal however not on my Linux Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command names in Ubuntu are [case sensitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity), so `CHMOD` is not the same as `chmod`:

```bsh
$ ls -l file
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dessert dessert 0 Jun  1 13:25 file
$ CHMOD 400 file
CHMOD: command not found
$ chmod 400 file
$ ls -l file
-r-------- 1 dessert dessert 0 Jun  1 13:25 file
```

Give lowercase `chmod` a try!

Comment: Thanks for your help, however i have tried the lowercase it returns no errors and yet still cannot ssh to my ec2 instance

Comment: @user195992 Then `chmod` is not the issue – please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1042555/edit) your question and provide more information (see [ask]). You may also want to take the [tour].

Comment: you have saved my day when i saw your comment i said i wil try oncemore and it worked with the lowercase you mentioned chmod I was able to ssh to my ec2instance and updated all.  thanks.  i will also take the tour to learn more